# Multiple chain in Replace

Tags: jquery

How do I do multiple chain for Replace for the salutation Ms, Cik, Mr, Encik, Puan, Mdm, Mrs -> 7 text in total

What I have currently is only for 2 text

```
$("h1").each(function() {
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Ms', '').replace('Cik', ''));
});
```

My HTML sample is as follows. I need to hide the above salutation

```
<h1>Dr Phillips</h1>
<h1>Ms Peter</h1>
<h1>Mr Robert</h1>
<h1>Prof Thomas</h1>
<h1>Mdm Khoo</h1>
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/mxm2oL0a/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression which contains all the values you want to replace, like this:

```js
$("h1").text(function(i, t) {
  return t.replace(/^(Ms|Cik|Mr|Encik|Puan|Mdm|Mrs)(?:\W)/, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Dr Phillips</h1>
<h1>Ms Peter</h1>
<h1>Mr Robert</h1>
<h1>Prof Thomas</h1>
<h1>Mdm Khoo</h1>
```

Note that the `^` character defines that we only want to find the text at the start of the string. The `(?:\W)` specifies that we want to capture the group as a whole word only. This isn't strictly necessary given your example, but is more robust.

Also note the use of the handler function provided to `text()` which negates the need for an explicit loop.

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant answer and explanation!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

In additional to Rory McCrossan's solution,

pay attantion that if you only want to get the 2nd word you can simply do this:

```js
$("h1").each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().split(" ")[1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Dr Phillips</h1>
<h1>Ms Peter</h1>
<h1>Mr Robert</h1>
<h1>Prof Thomas</h1>
<h1>Mdm Khoo</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!